# backoffice macro returns 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco8

i am getting the url 404 not found when loading in a macro.

[image]

But then i get in the console a

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44351/umbraco/api/prisinformation/produktlista?typ=1&version=0'.No action was found on the controller 'PrisInformation' that matches the name 'produktlista'.

and a
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44351/umbraco/api/prisinformation/produktlista?typ=0'.No action was found on the controller 'PrisInformation' that matches the name 'produktlista'.

the code i try to call is this one. no mather how much i try i get this error when calling the macro.

```
public class PrisInformationController : UmbracoApiController
  {
    private ILoginService _userService;
    private MembershipHelper _membershipHelper;

    public PrisInformationController(MembershipHelper membershipHelper, ILoginService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _membershipHelper = membershipHelper;
    }

    public void Authorize()
    {
        if (!_membershipHelper.IsLoggedIn())
        {
            if (_userService.AddAndOrLoginMember())
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        throw new HttpException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Page not found").ToString());
    }

    [HttpGet, HttpPost]
    [Route("produktlista/{typ}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Produktlista(int typ = 0, int version = 0)
    {
        Authorize();

        string result = string.Empty;
        string apiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"];
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl + "/databoken/get/produktlista/" + typ + "/" + version);

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            var response = request.GetResponse();

            string s = string.Empty;

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I read it as your Produktlista method has a route defined that requires you to do `/umbraco/api/prisinformation/produktlista/1` where 1 is typ, instead of ?typ=1. I could totally be wrong though, but maybe try removing the custom Route definition and see if that helps?

https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Routing/Umbraco-API-Controllers/index-v8

On another note you can change your controller to be of type UmbracoAuthorizedApiController which will do the backoffice auth check for you. Just note that it will change the standard route to be `/umbraco/backoffice/api/...` instead.